# HTML webside URL change should work with PYTHON script on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi, webserver, gpio

I tried to run a Python script to controll my led's via GPIO. With a HTML interface i want to communicate with the script. On the Website are only buttons which changes the url for example to http:local.host:/set/mode/pin/strip/color. For each button different numbers.

Im not able to run the script on a webserver. i tried it with lighttpd but failed.
I was able to connect to my html file but when it changes the url there is the 404 error. (of course, it gets nothing back to load)

I tried it with the module bottle (little webserver) but its not working either.
(with @route ("/set/mode/pin/strip/color") )
I already had an old bad wrote script and it worked fine with bottle but now i upgraded and now it wont work. btw bottle was not reliable on long sight, it crashed after a while.

From my HTML interfaces these are some Buttons which changes the url.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/0///'" class="button head black" value="Reset"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3///0'" class="button head red" value="Rot"></td>   
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3///1'" class="button head green" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3///2'" class="button head blue" value="Blau"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2//0/'" class="button black" value="Strip 0"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/0//'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/1//'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/2//'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
</tr>   <tr>
    <td>
</table>
```

My Python script. After i failed several times i tried sth with urlopen but i m not sure if i undertood it right.
You dont need to check the full code. the problem is propably in main() and or also in webside()

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#from bottle import route, run

#@route ("/led.html")
def webside():
    with open("led.html", "r") as file:
        content = file.read()
        print("return sth")
    return content

class Processing():
    state_pin = [28]

    def output_check(self, pin):
        settings = self.get_settings_file()
        for pos in range(len(settings)):
            if settings[pos] == pin:
                return True
        return False

    def set_state_pin(self, pin, value):
        self.state_pin[pin] = value

    def get_state_pin(self, pin):
        return self.state_pin[pin]

    def create_string(self, input):
        new_string = ""
        for text in input:
            new_string += text + ","
        new_string[-1] = ""
        return new_string

    def get_settings_file(self):
        try:
            with open("gpio.txt", "r") as file:
                settings = file.read().split(",")
                return settings
        except OSError:
            with open("gpio.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write(self.create_string(self.default_settings()))
                print(file + " created")

    def add_pin_file(self, mode, pin):
        with open("gpio.txt", "w+") as file:
            settings = file.read().split(",")
            if settings != pin:
                settings += pin
            file.write(self.create_string(settings))

    def del_pin_file(self, mode, pin):
        with open("gpio.txt", "w+") as file:
            settings = file.read().split(",")
            for pos in range(len(settings)):
                if settings[pos] == pin:
                    del settings[pos]
                    break
            file.write(self.create_string(settings))

    def default_settings(self):
        return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]  # all pins


    def get_strip(self, pos):
        strips = [[1,2,3],           # strip 0
                [4,5,6],            # strip 1
                [7,8,9],            # ...
                [10,11,12],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                ]
        return strips[pos]


    def get_color(self, pos):
        colours = [[1,4,7,10,13,17],  # red
                [],                 # green
                []                  # blue
                ]
        return colours[pos]


#@route ("/set/<mode>/<pin>/<strip>/<color>")
def set(mode, pin, strip, color):
    print("set sth")
#    urlopen("http://192.168.0.32/set/{}/{}/{}/{}".format(mode, pin, strip, color)).read()
    process = Processing()

    # reset/set
    if mode == 0:
        for pins in process.get_settings_file():
            GPIO.output(pins, mode)
            process.set_state_pin(pins, mode)

    # single pin
    if mode == 1:
        if process.output_check(pin):
            if process.get_state_pin(pin):
                GPIO.output(pin, 0)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, 0)
            else:
                GPIO.output(pin, 1)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, 1)

    # one strip
    if mode == 2:
        pins = process.get_strip(strip)
        value = 1

        for pin in pins:
            if process.get_state_pin(pin):
                value = 0

        for pin in pins:
            if process.output_check(pin):
                GPIO.output(pin, value)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, value)

    # one color
    if mode == 3:
        pins = process.get_color(color)
        value = 1

        for pin in pins:
            if process.get_state_pin(pin):
                value = 0

        for pin in pins:
            if process.output_check(pin):
                GPIO.output(pin, value)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, value)

    return webside()

def main():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    settings = Processing().default_settings()
    for pin in settings:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    try:
        mode = 0
        pin = 0
        strip = 0
        color = 0
        var = [0,0,0,0]
        while True:
            urlopen("http://192.168.0.32/set/{}/{}/{}/{}".format(mode, pin, strip, color)).read()
            if mode != var[0] or pin != var[1] or strip != var[2] or color != var[3]:
                var[0] = mode
                var[1] = pin
                var[2] = strip
                var[3] = color
                set(mode, pin, strip, color)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()

#run(host="0.0.0.0",port=88)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the error i get from the commandline:
[error_code_raspi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkawQ.png)

Its my first Question in this community. Hope i did everything right.
Can somebody give me hints ? Would be amazing i want to use my LED's :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tada here it is again, the confirmation im stupid af :D

maybe someone get to the same point. here is the solution. use bottle!
and the right port not like me.
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from bottle import route, run
import os

script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
script_dir = os.path.split(script_path)[0]
html_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "led.html")
gpio_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "gpio.txt")

@route ("/")
@route ("/led")
@route ("/led.html")
def website():
    print("website")
    with open(html_file_path, "r") as file:
        content = file.read()
    return content

state_pin = [None] * 30

class Processing():

    def output_check(self, pin):
        settings = self.get_settings_file()
        for pos in range(len(settings)):
            if int(settings[pos]) == int(pin):
                #print("output_check sucess")
                return True
        #print("output_check failed")
        return False

    def set_state_pin(self, pin, value):
        state_pin[pin] = value

    def get_state_pin(self, pin):
        return state_pin[pin]

    def create_string(self, input):
        new_string = ""
        for text in input:
            new_string += text + ","
        new_string[-1] = ""
        return new_string

    def get_settings_file(self):
        try:
            with open(gpio_file_path, "r") as file:
                settings = file.read().split(",")
                return settings
        except OSError:
            with open(gpio_file_path, "w") as file:
                file.write(self.create_string(self.default_settings()))
                return self.default_settings

    def add_pin_file(self, mode, pin):
        with open("gpio.txt", "w+") as file:
            settings = file.read().split(",")
            if settings != pin:
                settings += pin
            file.write(self.create_string(settings))

    def del_pin_file(self, mode, pin):
        with open("gpio.txt", "w+") as file:
            settings = file.read().split(",")
            for pos in range(len(settings)):
                if settings[pos] == pin:
                    del settings[pos]
                    break
            file.write(self.create_string(settings))

    def default_settings(self):
        return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]  # all pins


    def get_strip(self, pos):
        strips = [[0,1,2],           # strip 0
                 [3,4,5],            # strip 1
                 [6,7,8],            # ...
                 [9,10,11,],
                 [12,13,14],
                 [15,16,17],
                 [18,19,20],
                 [21,22,23]
                 ]
        return strips[pos]


    def get_color(self, pos):
        colours = [[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21],        # red
                  [ 1, 4, 7,10, 13, 16, 19, 22],        # green
                  [ 2, 5, 8,11, 14, 17, 20, 23]         # blue
                  ]
        return colours[pos]



@route ("/set/<mode>/<pin>/<strip>/<color>")
def set(mode, pin, strip, color):
    process = Processing()

    mode = int(mode)
    pin = int(pin)
    strip = int(strip)
    color = int(color)

    # reset/set
    if mode == 0:
        print("reset")
        for pins in process.get_settings_file():
            print(pins)
            GPIO.output(int(pins), mode)
            process.set_state_pin(int(pins), mode)

    # single pin
    if mode == 1:
        print(mode)
        if process.output_check(pin):
            if process.get_state_pin(pin):
                GPIO.output(pin, 0)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, 0)
            else:
                GPIO.output(pin, 1)
                process.set_state_pin(pin, 1)

    # one strip
    if mode == 2:
        pins = process.get_strip(strip)
        value = 1

        for pin in pins:
            if process.get_state_pin(int(pin)):
                value = 0

        for pin in pins:
            if process.output_check(int(pin)):
                GPIO.output(int(pin), value)
                process.set_state_pin(int(pin), value)

    # one color
    if mode == 3:
        pins = process.get_color(color)
        value = 1

        for pin in pins:
            if process.get_state_pin(int(pin)):
                value = 0

        for pin in pins:
            if process.output_check(int(pin)):
                GPIO.output(int(pin), value)
                process.set_state_pin(int(pin), value)

    return website()


def main():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    settings = Processing().default_settings()
    for pin in settings:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    print("setup")
    for pos in range(len(settings)):
        state_pin[pos] = 1

main()
run(host="0.0.0.0",port=80)
```

You guys are free to copy paste.
This script is to set red green blue on and off.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<titel></titel>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: intline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.head {
border: 2px solid #696969;
}
.left {
color: #696969;
}
.black {background-color: #e7e7e7e7;
    color: black;
}
.blue {background-color: #008CBA;}
.green {background-color: #4CAF50;}
.red {background-color: #f44336;}
.borderblue {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
.bordergreen {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
.borderred {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/99/99/99/99'" class="button head black" value="MT0"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/99/99/99/99'" class="button head black" value="MT1"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/99/99/99/99'" class="button head black" value="MT2"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/99/99/99/99'" class="button head black" value="MT3"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/0/99/99/99'" class="button head black" value="Reset"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3/99/99/0'" class="button head red" value="Rot"></td>   
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3/99/99/1'" class="button head green" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/3/99/99/2'" class="button head blue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/0/99'" class="button black" value="Hoher Schrank"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/0/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/1/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/2/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>   
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/1/99'" class="button black" value="Spiegel 1"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/3/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/4/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/5/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/2/99'" class="button black" value="Spiegel 0"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/6/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/7/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/8/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/3/99'" class="button black" value="Kleiner Schrank"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/9/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/10/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/11/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>   
   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/4/99'" class="button black" value="Tisch"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/12/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/13/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/14/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/5/99'" class="button black" value="Strip 5"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/15/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/16/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/17/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>   <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/6/99'" class="button black" value="Bett !rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/18/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/19/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/20/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/2/99/7/99'" class="button black" value="Tür"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/21/99/99'" class="button borderred" value="Rot"></td>
        <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/22/99/99'" class="button bordergreen" value="Grun"></td>
    <td>
<input type=button onClick="location.href='/set/1/23/99/99'"  class="button borderblue" value="Blau"></td>
   </tr>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thx for nothing and a nice day :)